# Extract text from html file using java

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am working on a text crawler and I need to extract a certain text from several sites. I have used jsoup html parser:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.aljazeera.net/programs/behindthenews/2014/11/9/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A8%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1").get();
Elements ps = doc.select("p");
String s = Jsoup.parse(ps.text()).text();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("newFile.txt", "UTF-8");
out.write(s);
out.close();
```

This algorithm gets me an unwanted text, the wanted text is under this tag `<p dir="rtl">`

And when I change my selection to `Elements ps = doc.select("p dir=rtl");`, it returns a compilation error.

Is there any way to make it just select this wanted tag?

Comment: Are you sure that website has the `<p dir="rtl">` tag? I couldn't find the tag in the web page source.

Comment: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: @NavidShakibapour yes, this tag is not in the main link it is in one of its sub-links

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom thank you this is helpful, but could you please help me which syntax to choose cause i do not know which one to choose

Comment: Can you update the question so that it has the exact link you are expecting to have the `<p dir="rtl">` tag?

Comment: @NavidShakibapour http://www.aljazeera.net/programs/behindthenews/2014/11/9/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A8%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1

Answer (score 0):

The below code will capture all the `<p dir="rtl">` tags:

```
String uri = URI.create("example.com").toASCIIString();
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(uri).get();
Elements pElements = doc.select("p[dir=rtl]");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Element element : pElements) {
    sb.append(element.text());
}

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("newFile.txt", "UTF-8");
out.write(sb.toString());
out.close();
```

The only tricky thing is that, you need to use encoded URLs (and not the one with Arabic letters).

**Edit 1:** 
URL encoding can be done in the code.

Answer (score 0):

> the wanted text is under this tag <p dir="rtl">

You need to use the following CSS query:

```
p          /* Select any p element... */
[dir=rtl]  /* ... with a 'dir' attribute set to "rtl" */
```

> @NavidShakibapour [http://www.aljazeera.net/programs/behindthenews/2014/11/9/أسباب-ودلالات-استمرار-الصدام-بجامعات-مصر](http://www.aljazeera.net/programs/behindthenews/2014/11/9/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A8%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1)

The above url need to be encoded. We'll use the URI#create helper method. On the returned `URI` instance, we'll invoke the `toASCIIString` method.

```
URI uri = URI //
           .create("http://www.aljazeera.net/programs/behindthenews/2014/11/9/أسباب-ودلالات-استمرار-الصدام-بجامعات-مصر") //
           .toASCIIString();
```

Here is a working sample code:

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.aljazeera.net/").get();

Elements sublinks = doc.select("a[href*=/programs/behindthenews]");
System.out.println("Sublinks found: " + sublinks.size() + "\n*****");

for (Element sublink : sublinks) {
    String url = URI.create(sublink.absUrl("href")).toASCIIString();

    Document subLinkPage = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    System.out.println(subLinkPage.select("p[dir=rtl]"));
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
}
```

#### OUTPUT (content stripped)

```
Sublinks found: 5
*****
<p dir="rtl">وحول هذا الموضوع وصف مدير مكتب الجزيرة في موسكو زاور شوج قرار الرئيس بوتين بالخطوة المفاجئة، باعتبار أن الروس وضعوا سقفا زمنيا مفتوحا لتدخلهم العسكري، يتراوح بين 12 و18 شهرا.</p>
<p dir="rtl">
(...)
-------------------------
<p dir="rtl">وحول هذا الموضوع وصف مدير مكتب الجزيرة في موسكو زاور شوج قرار الرئيس بوتين بالخطوة المفاجئة، باعتبار أن الروس وضعوا سقفا زمنيا مفتوحا لتدخلهم العسكري، يتراوح بين 12 و18 شهرا.</p>
<p dir="rtl">
(...)
-------------------------
(...)
```